# How does view's stylesheet interact with model's ::FontRole in Qt model/view environment?

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

What happens when font family and size supplied by stylesheet of QTreeView differ from the ones returned by the model assigned to it? So far it seems like model's data overrides stylesheet settings. How do I change font of a view with a custom model assigned to it then?

Or to be more precise: if I know I want to style the view with stylesheet - what do I return from model when ::FontRole is requested?

UPD: just in case I am doing something stupid, here is my stylesheet that I assign to qtreeview:

```
QTreeView::item:selected
{
    color: black;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

QTreeView::item:has-children
{
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-bottom-color: green ;
    border-top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I think the default, which would be QVariant().

Comment: sadly, this does not work. this is actually the reason for my question. I can set color of the text this way without any problems, but font from stylesheet is completely ignored

Comment: Seems that TreeView does not support customization of fonts. Create your own delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some asking around and googling it turned out that styling text in QTreeView should be done on QTreeView instead of QTreeView::item

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar issue with QHeaderView. The style should be on QHeaderView rather than QHeaderView::section.